# WP_Query() displaying past post / event

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, meta-query, date

I'm making a page for past events (using Event Expresso plugin) and I'm kinda confused about the wp_query.

This one works:

```
$atts = array(
      'title' => NULL,
      'limit' => 100,
      'css_class' => NULL,
      'show_expired' => true,
      'month' => NULL,
      'category_slug' => NULL,
      'order_by' => 'event_start_date',
      'sort' => 'DESC',
      'date_query' => array(
          array(
              'column' => 'event_start_date',
              'before' => '1 month ago',
          ),
      ),
    );
```

However, this one won't work (it will still show event past May 11):

```
$atts = array(
      'title' => NULL,
      'limit' => 100,
      'css_class' => NULL,
      'show_expired' => true,
      'month' => NULL,
      'category_slug' => NULL,
      'order_by' => 'event_start_date',
      'sort' => 'DESC',
      'date_query' => array(
          array(
              'column' => 'event_start_date',
              'before' => '2020-05-11 23:59:59',
          ),
      ),
    );
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

The column 'event_start_date' returns the event date when I do print_r($post->event_start_date); inside a post loop.

I'm really confused why the 2nd code does not work.

I also tried

```
'before' => 'now',
```

and

```
'before' => 'today',
```

and its not working. :(

Comment: When I search for 'Expresso Express' I can't even find anything WordPress related, just coffee stuff.  Is that a plugin of sorts?  Do they have a support forum?

Comment: Sorry, it should be Event Expresso, thank you for pointing out. I've corrected it already.

Comment: The `column` field only works against the `wp_posts` table date columns. These are `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_modified`, and `post_modified_gmt`.

Comment: `event_start_date`, I assume, is a meta field set on event posts by the plugin. To select against a meta field, you'd need to use a [meta query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters), not a date query:

Comment: But are you sure that your first code actually works? As far I understand you want to display posts more recent than that date, so you should use `after` not `before`.